# Undo ticked Required field for due date

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

How do I undo tick the Required box for the Due Date field in Azure DevOps.

The properties of the field have been inherited from another work item that I can't find.

The get the Field Reference Name: Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.DueDate.

Please advice?

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

To make a required field optional, you need to:

Firstly, check whether you are using Inherited process or XML process. In Organization Settings -> Process. The inherited process should be under a Basic process and the XML process begins with an icon like "</>".

If you are using inherited process:

Go to Organization Settings -> Process -> click that process -> select your work item type -> edit the field -> select "Options" tab -> un-check the "Required" checkbox.

If you are using XML process:

Go to Organization Settings -> Process -> export and unzip it -> go to `..\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions` -> open your work item type definition -> search for your field definition -> delete `<REQUIRED />` -> save and archive it -> click "import process" in Azure DevOps -> select your file and check "Replace existing template".